# Inherit from a generic Hub

Tags: signalr

Assume I have a base class like this :

```
public class CustomizedHub<M> : Hub
{
...
}
```

and now I want to inherit all of **practical** hubs from this base class , but I get the following error :

```
Type CustomizedHub`1<M> is a generic type definition
```

The main reason for above error is SignalR tries to resolve the base class as a practical hub too. How can I enforce it to avoid this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just make your base class as an **abstract** class :

```
 public abstract class CustomizedHub<M> : Hub
{
...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can write your own implementation of `IHubDescriptorProvider`, which will take care of skipping generic base classes during the registration process. You can check the default behavior [here](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core/Hubs/Lookup/ReflectedHubDescriptorProvider.cs). You will inject your implementation through the `DependencyResolver`, as explained [here](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/extensibility/dependency-injection) (that infrastructure can be used to replace any stock service implementation with your own).

Comment: making it abstract is simpler :)

Comment: @MahmoudMoravej you are right, goot to know. Actually it's quite clear from the code I referenced, but I did not notice it :)  https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core/Hubs/Lookup/ReflectedHubDescriptorProvider.cs#L89